# HTML text is broken when special character like "<", ">" and "&" in string using vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, html-escape-characters

I am working in desktop application. I have string which is display in `formatelinklabel` control as HTML text. This HTML text contains special character like  `<`, `>` and `&`. Because of these character, it is not display properly as HTML text.

My string is like this :

```
<b>Details: </b>  !"#$%'()*+,-/:;=?@[\]^_`{|}~&><)<br/> <b> Take: </b> test tab. <br/> <b>  Quantity: </b>  <br/><b> Days Supplied:  </b> 90 <br/>
```

When i tried to display this string in control it is not display like HTML formatted text and its format is broken and display plain text.

So Can anyone tell me how to escape these characters and display HTML text properly?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to display for example like `<span>Hello</span>` or just the `Hello`?

Comment: I think you need to use [html encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx) or [html decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode.aspx)

Comment: @Nunners I am looking for display just Hello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to replace your special characters by their HTML code ?

For example, `&` could be replaced by `&amp;` . I did it with a C# project and it worked, I suppose it could be the same with VB.NET

You can find all codes [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: can you provide part of code to display this using replace characters by their HTML code? It is really help to figure out this issue. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a string like `myString = My name is <strong>Patel</strong>`, you have to replace it by `myString = My name is &lt;strong&gt;Patel&lt;/strong&gt;`. I think you can also replace it by their HTML number as described in the link above, I never tried...

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `String.Replace` method on your string object and use the following link to replace the correct values

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Example:

```
string testStr = "!"#$%'()*+,-/:;=?@[\]^_`{|}~&><";
testStr = testStr.Replace("<", "&lt;");

Result : 

!"#$%'()*+,-/:;=?@[\]^_`{|}~&>&lt;
```

Notice that your `<` character has been replaced by the `&lt;` html should now render this correctly.